# How to return table name when corresponding column is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, html-table

I want to get title of the table whenever I click on the corresponding columns. In my example both the title of the columns and the rest of the rows are created dynamically.

My dynamically generated table

```
tr = $('<tr/>');
$.each(vendor_name, function(j, vendor) {
    tr.append($("<td/>").html('<label >'+vendor_name[j]+'</label>'));// column names
})

 $('#tbl_items').append(tr);

$.each(result, function(i, item) {
   tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append($("<td/>").html('<label >'+item['ITEM_NAME']+'</label>'))                              
    tr.append("<td>" + item['QUANTITY'] + "</td>");
    $.each(vendor_name, function(k, vendor) { 
        tr.append($("<td/>").html('<label name="qty" class="name">'+item["'"+vendor_name[k]+"'" ]+'</label>')); 
    });
    $('#tbl_items').append(tr);
});

<table id='tbl_items'><table>
```

NB: This table is populated from a dynamic pivot query so that i have used the above method to display the table in my jsp page.

Display / get column names based on the mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you're looking to have a click event on each column (`td`) which returns the column's dynamically-generated `label`.

You can accomplish it this way:

```
$('#tbl_items td').click(function() {
  getColumnName(this);
});

function getColumnName(item) {
  var el = $(item).find('label').attr('name');
  console.log(el);
}
```

Then just replace the console.log with a return, at your leisure.

Comment: I have a dynamically generated textbox how can i get values of that text box.  tr.append($("<td/>").html('<input type="text" name="cmpny_id" id="cmpny_id"'+p+' value="'+vendor_name[p]+'"/>'));     @Pangolin

Comment: Using the same function provided above, replace $(item).find('label').attr('name') with the following:  $(item).find('input').val()